# this.$.<id> syntax giving me error when retrieving data from firebase with polymer

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am using polymer and firebase, and I wanted to retrieve data from the database once. To achieve this, I did something like this inside my custom element:

```
 ready: function(){
    this.$.query.ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      this.$spinner.removeAttribute('active');
    });
  }
```

And I have

```
      <paper-spinner id="spinner" active></paper-spinner>
```

This inside my element

Now, this gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'spinner' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I not use the this.$. syntax inside that function for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line should be like this :
this.$.spinner.removeAttribute('active');

you are missing "dot" after the $ sign.